# Upgrade to Neo4jClient 1.0.0.651 results in NullReferenceException

Tags: neo4jclient

I have a working solution that is using Neo4jClient 1.0.0.646 with no problem.  When I install the nuget package for the latest 1.0.0.651 I receive a NullReferenceException on every attempt to return query results.  Given the stack trace details below can someone diagnose the issue for me?  I am on Json.NET 5.0.6 if that is relevant.  I see the REST calls going out and coming back with the correct data so the Cypher is good.

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467261   Message=Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.   Source=Neo4jClient   StackTrace:
>          at Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherQuery.b__0(String
>   current, String paramName) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherQuery.cs:line
>   46
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1
>   source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)
>          at Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherQuery.get_DebugQueryText() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherQuery.cs:line
>   43
>          at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.<>c__DisplayClass1e`1.<Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteGetCypherResultsAsync>b__1d(Task`1
>   responseTask) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line
>   825
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()   InnerException:

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough of the exception detail for me to identify exactly where this is occurring.

Please include the full text of the exception in a new issue at https://github.com/readify/Neo4jClient/issues/new

Here are all the changes since 1.0.0.646, if you want to take a peek for anything related to what you're doing: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/compare/v1.0.0.646...master

Comment: I have updated the original post with full text of the exception thrown.